# When I edit someone else's answer will I also gain reputation for any upvotes it receives since the (approved) edit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I really hesitate to edit someone else's answer - especially if it is the accepted one - and would much rather provide my own as an alternative instead. This way the upvoting community can simply decide which they regard to be best.

I recently had the unpleasant experience of one answer of mine getting deleted by a moderator. The fact that you do not learn why this is up-front is unnerving enough by itself. I had to flag for moderator intervention (hoping a plea to revert would make them reconsider) to learn that they wanted me to suggest an edit instead...

... which I ultimately, and hesitatingly, perhaps even grudgingly, did.  Which leads me to this question:

When you edit someone else's answer will you also gain reputation for any upvotes it receives since the (approved) edit?

If not, should that not be the case? - just so that there is a better incentive to choose editing over simply providing a new answer which you know will gain you reputation (presuming it's any good).

Comment: No, pretty sure you'll only get (I think) 2 rep points for performing an edit (up until you reach like 2000 total rep).  Edits should be minor and not change the core of the answer anyway.  If you're making edits such that you think you should be receiving rep for you contribution beyond the 2 points mentioned above, I think you may be misunderstanding the reasoning behind editing.

Comment: @zero298, case in point is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55244659/5110545). My edit - which was previously an answer by itself - clearly stands-out.  Tell me whether you think this was done right, or that my answer got deleted for the wrong reasons...

Comment: @zero298 you only gain rep from the first 500 suggested edits, so 1000 rep max.

Comment: Fixing stale links should probably just be an edit.  The core of the answer is still the same.  However, I don't know that the answer should even be updated.  It makes more sense to just point to where the canonical "latest" version can be found without having to hardlink to a specific version.

Comment: And if someone made a trivial, consequential, or even detrimental edit for a great post that continue to gets upvotes after the edit... should they get rewarded as well? And if not, how would you distinguish the great edits that deserve rewards from the other edits? And what about users with more than 2k, that no longer get any reputation from edits?

Comment: @zero298, the reason I hesitate is that the link in the accepted answer is not just stale, I did not provide an alternative link to the same original resource. Imho it really is a different means to the same end.

Comment: The edit in the answer you linked includes a paragraph of irrelevant commentary that doesn't belong in an answer. You can leave a comment if you want to alert the author about why you added the information.

Comment: @yivi, I realize that the challenges involved to do it fairly are likely among the many reasons this was never attempted.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - I agree it doesn't belong in the answer an sich. But because it's called "suggesting an edit" I was expecting the original author to review and cherry-pick it for incorporation before going public and I felt I had to justify my reasons for doing so. Again, I would never even have attempted editing if my own original answer hadn't been deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

No, editors will not receive any reputation from subsequent votes on the post - whether votes are up or down. The only reputation reward for edits is 2 points per edit for the first 500 edits as long as editor's overall reputation is below 2000. After one reaches 2000 reputation points there is no reputation rewards for edits (and no review requirement).

Rewarding edits for future upvotes would encourage pointless edits to popular posts to gain reputations and thus not going to be implemented. Documentation effort (no longer visible) on SO had reputation setup similar to proposed one and indeed it lead to large amount of edits just to join popular pages.

"Rewarding" editor with negative point for future downvotes on the post is cleverly excluded from the proposal - also that actually may be beneficial to encourage more complete edits that turn questions. Note that this is somewhat implemented on  the site as reputation is "taken away" for edits on posts that are removed (this is not real "removal" - reputation is just representation of *visible* impact on the site which indeed is 0 for no longer visible posts).

---

On you specific post that was deleted: please note that there are 3 ways to post content on SO:

- questions - should contain one coding related question with enough details that anyone with reasonable knowledge in the given technology can understand what is being asked.
- answers - should contain a complete answer to the given question *as asked*. It may contain multiple variants of answer as well as additional information that may help original poster with actual problem they have.
- comments - should contain clarification questions/information related to particular post  where comment is made. Ideally information from comment is incorporated into the post and comment deleted as "no longer needed". Comments are not expected to last forever.

What you posted as an "answer" did not contain an answer to the question but was a commentary on some other post. It either should have been posted as a comment or turned into a complete answer. Since it was not converted into complete answer post was deleted (note that votes don't play role in making content appropriate for a given type of post).

Comment: What changes then, in your opinion, would have been able to warrant it a "real" answer status? Imho, at face value either "answer" boils down to "here's a link to where you might find what you are looking for".  The difference only being the places being linked to.  Then if one qualifies (or doesn't), then so (or neither) should the other; the fact that one is phrased as commentary to the other doesn't make it less valuable.

Comment: And indeed, in all fairness it would have to work reciprocally for downvotes, too.

Comment: @cueedee I don't see reasons to create "partial answer" status. You are welcome to ask separate question as true "feature-request" with clear explanation what you proposing and *why it is useful for the site*.

Answer (score 3):

To add a more direct opinion on this question

> When you edit someone else's answer will you also gain reputation for
>   any upvotes it receives since the (approved) edit?
>
> If not, should that not be the case? - just so that there is a better
>   incentive to choose editing over simply providing a new answer which
>   you know will gain you reputation (presuming it's any good).

The editor's *expertise* isn't being rewarded, so giving editors the same upvotes when they edit a post is equivalent to stealing credit for someone else's work.  The reward for editing posts at all is 2 reputation, capped at 1000 rep total, and that only counts if your own reputation is below 2000 reputation.

Comment: So now the answer's original author is being fully rewarded for knowledge contributed by an editor, how is that - if you want to frame it as such - not considered "stealing"? Btw, I never meant to suggest that editors receive the same credit as authors for upvotes; but _some_ credit would seem, well, fair.

Comment: It's the difference between cooking a meal and taking a picture of a meal.  The person taking the picture only contributed to the presentation of the meal in some capacity; someone else (or others - depending on how big the meal is) actually spent the time and effort into *making* all of that.  2 reputation is *plenty* of credit for someone who edits posts.